# WCF Return Multiple Function Results Asynchronously?

Tags: wcf, web-services, asynchronous, wcf-ria-services

I've been reading up on how to do this but I'm having a hard time getting my head around it.

[Synchronous and Asynchronous Operations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734701.aspx)

[WCF: Working with One-Way Calls, Callbacks, An...](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163537.aspx)

My goal is to return results from multiple functions in a Silverlight enabled WCF service as they are discovered.

A general overview of how this service is desired to work is as follows.

User enters a url that has many large csv files listed in hyperlinks. The service gets the initial user entered url, makes a web request of that url, gets the csv file names using regex, service downloads the csv files to server, files are converted to a different format.

Currently all of that works, but no response is shown until the entire operation is done. I would like to provide feedback during each function.

I'm using VB for this app but am fluent in C# if anyone has a code suggestion.

```
<ServiceContract(Namespace:="http://somemadeupurl")>
<SilverLightFaultBehavior()>              
<AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode:=
             AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)>
Public Class GetCSV

  <OperationContract()>
  Public Function ProcessInitialLink(ByVal strInitialLink As String)
  'download the source html

  'do a webrequest and extract  csv links   
  'since dates are in the filenames I would like to send back most 
  'recent to user here

    Dim strMostRecentCSV As String=SomeRegexMatch
> 'problem here. Would like to return strMostRecentCSV and keep processing
    GetAndConvertBigCSV(strMostRecentCSV)   
    Return strMostRecentCSV
  End Function

  'actually a list but for brevity..
  Private Function GetAndConvertBigCSV(ByVal strMostRecentCSV as string) 
    'do a bunch of downloading
    'call a function to do a bunch of converting
    'call a function to clean up files
  End Function
End Class
```

If it's done like this it will return `strMostRecentCSV` but has to wait until `GetAndConvertBigCSV` is done before returning.

I've tried spawning `GetAndConvertBigCSV` as a new thread and it works but returns nothing  that I can bind to the Silverlight client    (e.Result)

At a minimum I would like to provide feedback of the first function `Return` then have the service continue.

Thanks a million for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would NOT recommend using a polling duplex to solve this business requirement, due to the load it places in the server.  What I read was that you have a need to return several files back to the client, and provide feedback to the client as the files are being downloaded.

As downloading a file does not seem to be an issue (which should be a stream), I think you are asking is how to update the UI, while the files are being downloaded, perhaps capturing how much of the file is actually being downloaded.  At the least, you should be updating the UI as each file arrives.

The latter is easy, simply download the download links to each file on the client, do them one by one, and update the UI between file downloads.  That would be a [single threaded approach](http://www.vbdotnetforums.com/remoting/82-webclient-download-progress.html).

Update the UI while a background thread is executing, is a more complicated approach, but a much better implementation, as the client "feels" that they remain in control while the files are being downloaded.  Here is an approach for [downloading a file async](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.downloadprogresschanged.aspx).

Remember in SilverLight, you really only have HTTP to transfer information to the application, which cannot do duplex.  HTTP long pooling achieves the same result, but connections are left open, and greatly minimize the ability to scale.

Comment: Thanks for your help. The info in your the second link "downloading a file async" is going to solve the UI updating.  I forgot that DownloadDataAsyc OpenReadAsync etc were available in the the framework. Those functions along with an event handler are really going to help out.  Thanks again

Comment: Thanks DaveCS - let me know if you have any other questions.  I've been working in SL for about 2 years, and with WCF, RX framework, MVVM Light Toolket, and the various emerging techniques around SL, it took awhile to learn!

Answer (score 2):

I think that what you probably want is a "polling duplex http service" - what this means is that WCF will fake up a duplex style service for you (by polling).  The advantage of a duplex service over a regular asynchronous service is that it is easy to call back to the client multiple times (so you can provide feedback on the progress of your task).

It is very easy to implement.  Let's say you have two projects a web application and a silverlight application...

### Web Application

Create your service, for example:

```
[ServiceContract(CallbackContract = typeof(ICallback))]
public interface ILongRunningService
{
    [OperationContract]
    void StartLongRunningProcess(string initialParameter);
}

[ServiceContract]
public interface ICallback
{
    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    void Update(string someStateInfo);
}

public class LongRunningService : ILongRunningService
{
    public void StartLongRunningProcess(string initialParameter)
    {
        // Get hold of the callback channel and call it once a second
        // five times - you can do anything here - create a thread,
        // start a timer, whatever, you just need to get the callback
        // channel so that you have some way of contacting the client
        // when you want to update it
        var callback = OperationContext
            .Current
            .GetCallbackChannel<ICallback>();

        ThreadPool
            .QueueUserWorkItem(o =>
                                   {
                                       for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
                                       {
                                           callback.Update("Step " + i);
                                           Thread.Sleep(1000);
                                       }
                                   });
    }
}
```

Then you need a svc file that has this in it (adjust the service attribute to be your service implementation class):

```
<%@ ServiceHost Service="SilverlightApplication.Web.LongRunningService" %>
```

Finally you will need this configuration inside web.config (this goes inside the configuration root element):

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <extensions>
    <bindingExtensions>
      <add name=
        "pollingDuplexHttpBinding"
          type="System.ServiceModel.Configuration.PollingDuplexHttpBindingCollectionElement,System.ServiceModel.PollingDuplex, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
    </bindingExtensions>
  </extensions>
  <services>
    <service name="SilverlightApplication.Web.LongRunningService">
      <endpoint
         address=""
         binding="pollingDuplexHttpBinding"
         bindingConfiguration="multipleMessagesPerPollPollingDuplexHttpBinding"
         contract="SilverlightApplication.Web.ILongRunningService">
      </endpoint>
      <endpoint
          address="mex"
          binding="mexHttpBinding"
          contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
    </service>        
  </services>
  <bindings>
    <pollingDuplexHttpBinding>
      <binding name="multipleMessagesPerPollPollingDuplexHttpBinding"
               duplexMode="MultipleMessagesPerPoll"
               maxOutputDelay="00:00:07"/>
    </pollingDuplexHttpBinding>        
  </bindings>
    <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="">
                <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
                <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
</system.serviceModel>
```

The important parts are the **name** attribute on the **service** element and the **contract** attribute on the **endpoint** element. They should be the class and interface you defined (with the namespace).

**IMPORTANT** You need to add a reference to the C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Silverlight\v4.0\Libraries\ **Server**\System.ServiceModel.PollingDuplex.dll assembly (remove the x86 if not 64 bit OS) to the web application project.

### Silverlight Application

You need to firstly add a service reference to the service you created and then, let's say you want to call the service from a button you would have the following code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{            
    // Create the client proxy with the URL of the service
    var proxy = new LongRunningServiceClient(
        new PollingDuplexHttpBinding(
            PollingDuplexMode.MultipleMessagesPerPoll),
        new EndpointAddress(
            "http://localhost/WebApplication/LongRunningService.svc"));

    // Attach the handler to be called periodically and start the process
    proxy.UpdateReceived += Update;                        
    proxy.StartLongRunningProcessAsync("blah");
}

private void Update(object sender, UpdateReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    // Use the result from the e parameter here
}
```

**IMPORTANT** You need to add a reference to the C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Silverlight\v4.0\Libraries\ **Client**\System.ServiceModel.PollingDuplex.dll assembly (remove the x86 if not 64 bit OS) to the silverlight client project.

And that is it - the Update method will get called, in this case once a second five times. but you can do whatever you like.

Comment: Thanks a million for that I'll give it a go on an upcoming project that is similar and see how it works out. I read a lot documents describing similar concepts but the way you explained it makes sense and something I can understand.  Thanks again, much appreciated.